# Cookie not reading or setting properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, postman

So I have a route in my Express app with two middleware in them:

`app.foo('/thisRoute', fancyMiddleware.one, fancyMiddleware.two);`

Both middlwares function in order just fine. However, in `fancyMiddleware.one` I have this:

```
var one = function(req, res, next) {
 ...
 ...
 res.cookie('myCookie', data, {maxAge: 3600000});

 console.log(req.cookies.myCookie)

 return next();
}
```

To test everything I'm using [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) to test all my requests.

The logged output for `req.cookies.myCookie` always returns `undefined`. But in the Body tab I can see that the cookie is present.

If I log out the same cookie in `fancyMiddleware.two` its also `undefined`.

**why is this returning undefined?**

EDIT: So, with a few answers of "why" being given, I now realize I should have also asked:

**How do I read the cookie I just set?**

I dont *really* need it right after I set it in `fancyMiddleware.one`, but I *do* need it in `fancyMiddleware.two`

EDIT 2: I forgot to mention I'm working with an Express 3 setup. Probably relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `req.cookies` is populated only once, when the cookie parser middleware is executed.

[`res.cookie()`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/f34944c539f3a8e0f35a7f41011635e40141fc3c/lib/response.js#L653-L679) immediately sets the `Set-Cookie` header, so you'll have to use `res.get('Set-Cookie')` to see the current values.

Comment: So in my server I have `app.use(connect.cookieParser());` set up. As I understand it, `app.use()` makes whatever middleware included fire on every route. I also tried moving my second middleware into another route, and then at the end of my first route redirecting to the second (thinking that would cause the cookie parser to fire). However, same results

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the cookie on the response-object `res`, but you are asking it from the request `req`.